# Register subscription from callback in Redux observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, subscription, redux-observable

`thirdPartyApiWithCallbackSubscription` keeps returning new data when I tried in Chrome console in promise mode. Now I want to move it to Observable and keep subscribing globally.
But in Observable mode, it just return data once. How should I refactor the code to keep receiving data whenever there is new data come through?

```
Observable.create(observer => {
  thirdPartyApiWithCallbackSubscription(data => {
    observer.next(data);
  });
})
.pipe(
  map(data => {
    return { type: 'DATA_CHANGED', payload: data };
  })
);
```

Comment: do you subscribe the redux store to the created observable, or how do you dispatch the action?

Answer (score 0):

Just verified `thirdPartyApiWithCallbackSubscription` got issues, the above method works as what I expected. Thanks.